# How to display search result of parent site and all sub-sites sharepoint 2010

Tags: search

I have a site collection like

http://example.com/site0

Site0 has site1 and site2 top level sites. Site1 has a few sub-sites and site2 has a few sub-sites

When the user searches in any of the sub-sites of site2, search result should display only from **site2 and its sub-sites.**

Answer (score 2):

You can define a search scope that defines the sites you want to include in the result set.

Comment: Thanks Mike .But defining scopes will be available to all other parentsite in the site collection.How to make defined scope to be availale only to Site2 and its subsites.

Answer (score 0):

Unforchenatly this scenario is not supported OOTB.

You will need to think about custom implementation.
for example you can use the keyword "**site**" and pass the site url, you'll get results form this site and its sub-sites.

Example:

```
http://example.com/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=site:"http://example.com/site/site2/"&cs=This Site&u=http://example.com/site/site2/
```